# Задать стили для элементов QMessageBox

Tags: c++, css, qt

Как добраться до конкретного элемента в QMessageBox? Какие у них objectName? У меня есть месседж-бокс с кнопками да и нет. Задать им обеим css можно через общее QPushButton, а как они по-отдельности называются?
Сейчас есть такой вариант, он не работает

```
void MattyGroupBox::deleteNote()
{
    QMessageBox MattyWTDNMsgBox;
    MattyWTDNMsgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    QMessageBox::StandardButton wantToDeleteNote;

    MattyWTDNMsgBox.button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("yesButton"));
    MattyWTDNMsgBox.setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("#yesButton {height: 53px;"
        "width: 53px;"
        "background-color: transparent;"
        "background-image: url(:/MattyNotes/CommonYes.png);"
        "background-position: center;"
        "background-repeat: no-repeat;"
        "color: transparent; "
        "font-weight: bold;"
        "font-style: italic; }"));
    //MattyWTDNMsgBox.button(QMessageBox::No)->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral());
    wantToDeleteNote = MattyWTDNMsgBox.question(this, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Удаление заметки"),
        QString::fromLocal8Bit("Вы точно хотите удалить"
            " эту заметку?"));
    if (wantToDeleteNote == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {
        DbManager::deleteNote(ThisGroupBoxNote.getNoteId());
        this->hide();
        this->~MattyGroupBox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте не кнопке стиль для кнопки присваивать, а именно `QMessageBox`.

Comment: То есть вот так? `WTDNMsgBox.setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("#yesButton {height: 53px;"}));` ? Пробовала, тоже не работает

Comment: Тогда или так `WTDNMsgBox.setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QPushButton#yesButton {height: 53px;}"));` или так `WTDNMsgBox.setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("QAbstractButton#yesButton {height: 53px;}"));` или даже так `WTDNMsgBox.button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("height: 53px;"));`

Comment: И обратите внимание, что у Вас закрывающая фигурная скобка не в кавычках.

Comment: Все варианты пробовала (сейчас еще раз проверила). Не работают. Если в любом из них убрать идентификатор, вместо него поставить QPushButton, то сработает для обеих кнопок. Это не относится к `WTDNMsgBox.button(QMessageBox::Yes)->setStyleSheet(QStringLi‌​teral("height: 53px;"));` Кстати он не подходит еще по той причине, что мне вообще нужно будет еще :hover прописывать. Да, скобка это только тут не туда влезла, я просто для примера убрала большой кусок css

Comment: Изменила пост, добавила побольше кода. Может быть, поможет найти проблему

Comment: Ну вот, как привели весь код, сразу ясно стало. Не надо использовать статический метод `MattyWTDNMsgBox.question()`. Если создаёте объект диалога, то либо метод `exec()`, либо `show()`. Иначе Вы стиль применяете тому объекту, который и не выводите вовсе.

Comment: ок, exec() сработал, спасибо. При show() сразу после открытия закрывается, но меня устраивает exec. Напишете ответ, чтобы отметить как правильный?

Comment: Метод `show()` имеет смысл использовать, если объект диалога будет создан через оператор `new`.

Comment: Вопрос, наверное, лучше удалить, поскольку он относится к разряду, скорее, опечатки, и в целом не несёт практической пользы сообществу. Ничего личного, у всех такое бывает и у меня в том числе периодически.